# Unable to use resources in production mode with tomcat

Tags: java, css, tomcat, gwt

I developed an application using GWT. It works alright in development mode. On the other hand when deployed all resources become unavailable. For example:

I have an image in:

```
mydomain.com/images/myimage.png
```

But when I deploy the application the image url becomes:

```
mydomain.com:8080/images/myimage.png
```

I already checked and the image is there (mydomain.com/images/myimage.png) the problem is about the used port.

I already tried the following ways to access my resources:

```
<g:Image url="/images/myimage.png" />
```

or

```
<g:Image url="../images/myimage.png" />
```

Both work in development mode but not in production with tomcat.

What am I doing wrong?

Also I'm deploying the app in webapps folder and the resources in the public_html folder.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple. I only had to remove the first bar: "images/myimage.png" getting the following result:

```
<g:Image url="images/myimage.png" />
```

Comment: For future reference the '.' and '..' are part of relative urls, using "./images/myimage.png" would also have worked, '.' refers to the current working directory, '..' looks in the directory directly above your current working directory.  I would check out relative urls you are sure to come across them in the future.  Cheers

Comment: @fe11e I didn't know that. I will try that option also. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean `url="../images/myimage.png"` to actually be `url="./images/myimage.png"` or do you actually have them in the directory above where your using them?

Answer (score 0):

Try appending [`HttpServletRequest#getContextPath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath%28%29) for your internal URLs:

```
url="${request.contextPath}/images/myimage.png"
```

Comment: But the css files that use the resources are on the client side.

Comment: Yes of course. But I still don't to know how to try your answer. How can I make an reference to the request.contextPath in the client?